# Storing a search string in VIM?

Tags: search, vim

I have a fairly elaborate regex string for finding IP addresses (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}. etc.)
If, for instance, I want to get all instances of the IP address, I have to delete everything in the line prior to the instance, and in a second call, I have to delete everything after the instance. Is there a way that I could store the search string as a variable to use in multiple replacements?

For instance:

```
    Store the string in register "a"
:y a 25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}\. . .
    Refer back to register "a" when deleting everything before the address
:%s/^.*(\a)/\1/g
    And again when deleting everything after it
:%s/(\a).*$/\1/g
```

BTW, I know you can delete before and after the parenthetical. I'm just using that as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to insert the contents of a register into the command line. From [`:help c_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R):

```
CTRL-R {0-9a-z"%#:-=.}                                  c_CTRL-R c_<C-R>
            Insert the contents of a numbered or named register.  Between
            typing CTRL-R and the second character '"' will be displayed
            to indicate that you are expected to enter the name of a
            register.
```

There's also a related [<kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> command](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-R) that may work better if you have certain unusual characters in your register.

Comment: Probably should add how to insert the contents into the register as the syntax in the question seems to suggest that is unknown as well.  To store into a register like described you probably want to use `:let @a = '25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}\. . .'`

Comment: Thanks! I figured I couldn't be the first person to have that idea.

Answer (score 0):

My [TaggedSearchPattern plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4123) can add a special neutral label to the search pattern itself, so that it can be easily identified in the search history ([`:help q/`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#q%2F)), and it also has mappings to just view the tagged searches. With this, you don't need to store the pattern in a separate Vim variable, as 8bittree's answer suggests.